# How can a index in a for loop be set but also be undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop in JS when I set a breakpoint inside the for a loop the index set it has a value in one usage but the other says undefined.

I have a breakpoint set at the line that starts `$("#send_hour option")`
If I mouseover index in the `for(index in availablehours)` it shows 09. If I mouseover index at the end `index);` it also shows 09. But if I mouseover index here `availablehours[index]` it shows as undefined?

```
var availablehours = {
    "09" : '9AM',
    "10" : '10AM',
    "11" : '11AM',
    "12" : 'Noon',
    "13" : '1PM',
    "14" : '2PM',
    "15" : '3PM',
    "16" : '4PM',
    "17" : '5PM',
    "18" : '6PM',
    "19" : '7PM'
};
```

How is this possible?

```
function refreshTheSendHoursWithAvailableHours(){
    console.log( "refreshTheSendHoursWithAvailableHours just called.");
      for(index in availablehours) {
       $("#send_hour option")[ $("#send_hour option").length] = new Option(availablehours[index], index);
      }
  }
```

Comment: The value of `index` is `09`. The value of the array element at that index `availablehours[index]` is undefined.

Comment: Ok, but I am mousing over index not what availablehours[index] is. Also, there is something at position 09 in available hours. Also the code is suppose to stuff all the items in availablehours in as options to a select. The for loop code above isn't creating them.

Comment: have not totally read the question, but debugger tool would have some bug, the most reliable way is access it through code (e.g. print to console).

Answer (score 0):

Doing a mouseover on `index` and mouseover on `availablehours[index]` will give two different values.

index : gives value of current index

availablehours[index] :  gives value of element stored in array at that index